# Kotlin integer constants with increasing values

Tags: kotlin

I want to create a series of integer constants with increasing values. Not an enum class, not objects, just integer constants that can be used as such.

In C, this can be done with an anonymous enum.

In Java, you have to resort to doing it by hand:

```
private static final int JANUARY = 1
private static final int FEBRUARY = 2
...
```

In Kotlin, do you have to fall back on the Java solution, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: you can make it using the companion object inside a class, and naming it `const val JANUARY = 1` and so on. const val are compile time constants (like static final). You can make them privates as well.

Comment: Answer for your question: there is no alternative to C anonymous enum. Your should fallback to Java solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply use [the const keyword](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#compile-time-constants)

In your case, that would mean

```
const val JANUARY = 1
const val FEBRUARY = 2
```

Where you want to put them depends on your use case, for example you can declare them top level or in companion objects, personally I dislike using companion objects unless Java compatibility is wanted